# I can't install npm packages in my Ionic project folder and get error hints: No repository field. No license field. How to fix it?

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, package, installation

Whatever npm package I try to install, I got such error hints:

```
"D:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" install ionic

Standard error:
npm WARN my-project-name@1.1.1 No repository field.
npm WARN my-project-name@1.1.1 No license field.

npm ERR! Cannot read property '0' of undefined

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\my-user-name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-08-28T03_14_36_746Z-debug.log

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm not familiar with `npm` and `node.js`, and I don't understand what the error hints mean.

The error log that it mentioned is a huge file with thousands of lines, which is even harder for me to understand. But basically I found the same error hints as the above at the bottom part of the log file.

I can install packages in the `node.js` folder with `npm` directive normally. But I just can't install them in my project (Ionic v1) folder, always getting the above three hints: `No repository field.` & `No license field.` & `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.

I installed the latest version of Ionic (3.9.2) in the `node.js` folder. But because my project was developed with Ionic v1, so I installed version 1.3.3 of Ionic in my project folder. Is it relevant to the error hints that I got?

And I can't downgrade `npm` successfully by running `npm install -g npm@4.2.0` command, getting such error hints:

```
D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules>npm install -g npm@4.2.0
npm ERR! path D:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! Refusing to delete D:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd: is outside D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm and not a link
npm ERR! File exists: D:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading NPM 
with `npm install -g npm@4.2.0`

Can you give bit more details: NPM version, on which folder you are running the install command and is your project connected with Git?

You can also try `npm init` in project directory to initialize repository and license etc if you want to [they are optional]

Comment: Thank you very much! My `npm` version is 5.3.0. I'm running the install command on my project folder (`E:\Projects\ProjectName\`). My project is not connected with Git.

Comment: I feel the issue might be with your NPM version. Did the downgrading NPM work?

Comment: I can't downgrade `npm` successfully, getting error hints: `code EEXIST` `Refusing to delete D:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd: is outside D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm and not a link` etc. I've edited the question and posted the whole error hints.

Answer (score 0):

To downgrade NPM in windows, you need to start the command prompt with Administrator privileges.
Right click on command prompt shortcut and choose Run as Administrator.

You can also set the properties of the shortcut to always Run as Administrator:
Right click -> properties -> Shortcut tab -> Advanced -> click Run as administrator checkbox

Installing NPM  as a different version now works
`npm install -g npm@4`

Note: If your NPM folder/install is missing, you will have re-install node.js to re-install NPM .